# Returning a 2-Dimensional Array from a method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to return a 2-dimensional array from a function inside of a class. I don't want to create a new array inside the function because I want to return the same one I've passed into the function.

I've tried creating a new array with the same name, but it says it's already defined within the scope. I've also tried just doing (return plane;) which doesnt work because of incompatible data types. I've also tried (return plane[][];) but that doesnt work either.

```
public class Airplane {
    private String maxSeats; //used for constructor
    private char[][] plane = new char[13][6]; //array to be passed in

 public char create(char[][] plane) {
       plane[13][6]; //this is where I'm unsure what to do
        //initialize them as '*' to start
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
            for ( int k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
                 plane[i][k] = '*';
            }
return plane;
        }
}
```

I'm trying to return the array to be used in another function where I will modify it.

Comment: The method is declared to return a `char`.  Change it to return a `char [][]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the return type to **char[][]** since you want to return a 2-dimensional array of characters and not just a single character

```
public class Airplane {
        private String maxSeats;
        private char[][] plane = new char[13][6];

        public char[][] create(char[][] plane) {

            // plane[13][6]; you should remove this line, it's the wrong syntax 
           //and it's unneeded since you've already declared this array

            // this is a more compact version of your nested loop
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
                Arrays.fill(plane[i], '*'); //fills the whole array with the same value
            }

            return plane;

        }
    }
```